# How to use Guard in place of Assert in TestInsight.DUnitX

Tags: delphi, spring4d, dunitx

I want to use the TestInsight.DUnitX with guard (Spring4D) but I get message 'No assertions were made during the test'

Is it possible to use the guard class in place of the assert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Spring.Guard` has nothing to do with `Assert` from DUnitX.

If you have unit tests that just pass because `Guard` (or basically any possible exception throwing code) did not raise then you need to satisfy DUnitX (or more precisely TestInsight) by simply calling `Assert.Pass` in your unit tests which basically tells it "I did not forget any checks - it's all fine".

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073187/587106